# Jquery Waypoints and using hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I've got jquery waypoints working as expected. Basically if a user scrolls up or down I add or remove a class to a certain div depending on where the div is in the viewport. The code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#names').waypoint('sticky', {
    offset: 60,
    stuckClass: 'stuck'
  });

  var bio_container = $('.bio-container');

  bio_container.waypoint({
    handler: function(direction,event) {
      var active_section = $(this);
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $(this).addClass('active');
      }
      else {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    },
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
  });
  bio_container.waypoint({
    handler: function(direction,event) {
      var active_section = $(this);
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
      else {
          $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    },
    offset: '300'
  });

});
```

Where things get hairy is based on that 'active' state I'm trying to manipulate a different part of the dom. I'm trying to use a jquery hasClass function to add a new class. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be picking up on the fact that the waypoints effected div has the 'active' class.

Here's my code for the hasClass:

```
$(function(){
  if ($('.steve > .bio-container').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#left-name').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

I don't know if the hasClass function is out of scope or if there's something else going on here. I'm really new to javascript so I'm really at a loss. I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Do you have a handler attached to your anonymous function? Right now it is not launching except on document ready

Comment: I do not. I'm guessing I'd need to put the hasClass within the initial two pieces of code? The "issue" there is that is that depending on which type of content is set as 'active' will determine which ID's I trigger. Seems like I'd want a nested if / else statement. The code that I didn't show in this example is the other piece of the hasClass. It looks like this (very similar, just different IDs).

Comment: Actually I got it sorted out. I added the hasClass within the original handlers and split out the classes (.bio-container) to be specific to the divs with ID's I was trying to manipulate. Thanks!

Comment: glad it could enlighten you